# Find out which repository package provides a command

Tags: debian, apt, command-not-found

When the package `command-not-found` is installed, a package is suggested if a command is invoked which is not installed, for instance

```
$ convert
The program 'convert' is currently not installed.  To run 'convert' please ask your administrator to install the package 'imagemagick'
convert: command not found
```

If `command-not-found` is not installed, is there an `apt` command I can invoke to find which package provides a specific binary? In this case the `apt-cache search` command is too unspecific.

Comment: Well there's `apt-file` (e.g. `apt-file search 'bin/gedit'`) - but that's likely not installed by default either. Is `apt-cache search --names-only gedit` specific enough?

Comment: `apt-file search /usr/bin/convert  | grep -w '/usr/bin/convert'`

Comment: @steeldriver It's better, but still you often get a long list of candidates. Also, if the name of the command in question is not a part of the package name it won't work (i changed "gedit" in the example to "convert" to reflect this).

Comment: @GAD3R That seems to work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Finding the package which provides a given command](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/530413/finding-the-package-which-provides-a-given-command)