# Finding the package which provides a given command

Tags: debian, apt

If the package `command-not-found` is installed and a user tries to run a command which is not present on the system, a suggestion is printed with the name of the package which provides the executable. Is there a command with the same functionality but which takes the name of an executable as an argument?

Edit: I have read [How to find out which (not installed) Debian package a file belongs to?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/6311/how-to-find-out-which-not-installed-debian-package-a-file-belongs-to) but none of the suggestions present a command which gives an unambiguous result like `command-not-found`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find out which (not installed) Debian package a file belongs to?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/6311/how-to-find-out-which-not-installed-debian-package-a-file-belongs-to)

Comment: @muru See edit.

Comment: I don't see anything ambiguous about the output of `package: filename`, but whatever you say.

Comment: @muru `apt-file search` requires and provides details which I don't care for, for instance you need to provide the path `/usr/bin` to the command in question.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use `command-not-found` itself:

```
command-not-found --ignore-installed ls
```

will tell you which package contains the `ls` command. (`--ignore-installed` avoids taking into account installed packages, and in particular ensures that the command isn’t run immediately if it’s already installed.)

Alternatively, you can use `apt-file`:

```
apt-file search bin/ls
```

will list all packages containing a file whose path contains “bin/ls”. You can filter this to match only `ls`:

```
apt-file search bin/ls | grep bin/ls$
```

Comment: `apt-file` has options `-x` (`--regexp`) and `-F` (`--fixed-string`), so you probably don't need to pipe to `grep`. For e.g., `apt-file search -lF bin/ls` => `coreutils`

Comment: @muru `-F` requires knowing the full path; `bin/` in a substring match will find binaries in `/bin`, `/sbin`, `/usr/bin` and `/usr/sbin`. `apt-file` with `-x` is very slow.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, the command is `command-not-found`:

```
$ command-not-found firefox
The program 'firefox' is currently not installed.  To run 'firefox' please ask your administrator to
install the package 'firefox-esr'
firefox: command not found
```

This has *exactly* the same functionality, because it is what the shell traps run to produce that output automatically already.

You can also use `apt-file search firefox` to find any matching *files* in a package.

Comment: Which packages provides this? On Centos 7 I have `command_not_found_handle` whose definition is just a shell function

Comment: On Debian, it’s in `command-not-found`.

Comment: One potentially annoying side-effect of this is that, if the command is available, it will be run immediately.

Comment: @Inian Fedora has `PackageKit-command-not-found`, the name is likely the same in CentOS if it uses PackageKit. (Presumably CentOS 8 will — it's still not out yet, right? — but I'm not sure if 7 did.) ETA: And `command_not_found_handle`, which is in `/etc/profile.d/PackageKit.sh`, is definitely provided by `PackageKit-command-not-found`.

Answer (score 0):

apt-file, with its perl regex, is almost able to perform the task... if only the file was verified to be installed somewhere in $PATH...

```bash
apt-file find --regexp "/$COMMAND$" | grep -E "($(tr : '|' <<< "$PATH"))/$COMMAND$""
```